# Is this question about why a website redirects to some other page on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I posted "[Weird redirection to another site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55300/weird-redirection-to-another-site)" to WebMasters Stack Exchange and it was immediately put on hold as off-topic. After reading the Help Centre there, I agree it is off-topic, so I wanted to check if it would be on topic here before I ask a moderator to move it.

What do you folks think?

Comment: Thank you for asking.

Comment: @CesarGon: Just delete the question, you've already figured out that if you're an end-user and having a browser related issue on a site, switch browsers. On the flip side, John Conde closed the question as off-topic because you don't control the code - so you could just post the code to a site you control, and magically it's on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's not on-topic for Web Applications either.

At first I thought that Super User would be the proper site to revert to, but having analysed the tags overthere, made me realize that you need to be at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, SO may be a good option.

Comment: Why wouldn't Super User be appropriate?

Comment: @Shog9 OP had done some research on the matter and found that `IE11` in combination with an `iframe` and `redirect` was causing the problem. The shear number of tags on SO, like the `redirect` and `iframe` and the programmatic knowledge at hand, made me suggest so.